How to write to a buffer from another buffer in C?
I don't know if this loop is good practice.
Is there a better way to write to a buffer from another buffer in C?
char temp_clientRecv[512] = {0};
for (int i=0; i<512; i++);
fprintf(stdout,"%c" ,temp_clientRecv[i]);


The semicolon at the end of the for loop line is a mistake.

Your code intents to write to stdout, not to a buffer.

@jonathan leffler yeah was pretty late when I asked this question and overlooked this. my intend was to have the fprintf function inside the for loop.


It will not compile as i is defined in the for loop scope and will not be declared outside this scope.

You do not write from one buffer to another only send the content of the temp_clientRecv out. If the output stream is buffered or not is out of the scope of C language. It depends on hardware, OS and implementation.

fprintf is an overkill.


fwrite(temp_clientRecv, 1, sizeof(temp_clientRecv), stdout);


"fprintf is an overkill." --> I used to think that too years ago, yet modern compilers often emit efficient code more like putchar(temp_clientRecv[i]).

@chux-ReinstateMonica The compiler isn't allowed to do that optimization in most cases since it changes the meaning of the code. For example in this case there's an implicit conversion from char to int due to the dysfunctional behavior of variadic functions. There may be sign extension during the conversion and in case of run-time values, the compiler won't be able to tell. Whereas putchar thanks to its dysfunctional API already takes an int as parameter and how that parameter ended up as int is none of putchar's business.

@chux-ReinstateMonica As one can quickly tell, all these functions from stdio.h are so horribly designed that the best advice is simply to stay clear from them in any production code and forget you ever heard of what will go down in history as the by far worst library ever designed for any system in any programming language.

@Lundin Wouldn't char be converted to int exactly the same way for both putchar and printf %c?

@IanAbbott Only if you pass a char to putchar - it expects an int so the caller might have an idea of what the function expects and convert in advance. Both functions have a broken design - a function named putchar should obviously take a char as parameter, if the person who designed the function had been sane.

@chux-ReinstateMonica it is even if it is optimized to putchar.

@Lundin putchar existed before function prototypes were a thing, so its parameter has to be an int for backwards compatibility. I don't really see a difference between converting a char to an int to match a parameter type, and converting a char to an int due to default argument promotions. Both putchar and printf %c convert the int to an unsigned char.

@IanAbbott Yes exactly, it's such an ancient outdated function is should already have been made obsolete long before C89. Not raised to canon status by getting included in the standard lib. Same thing with the whole of stdio.h.

@Lundin I think there would have been a few complaints if they did that! Another option would have been to only standardize the language and not the library.

@IanAbbott They should have ignored that. The aim of standardizations should be to follow best engineering practices. It's a well-known problem with standards that they block technical progress and innovation and this was already known in the 1980s. But no, all random trash functions from ancient 1970s Unix must be included in the C89 standard! And here we are 40 years later, still suffering from the existence of this skunkware.

@Lundin They've made a start with the strfromX functions, but they don't go far enough. We need versions of those functions that read from streams. Also formatted versions of the strtoX functions and versions of those that write to streams. Mostly to avoid reliance on variadic parameters.

If you are copying buffer to buffer in RAM without alteration in the data then you should use following code snippet in your code.
#include <string.h>

memcpy(void *dest_str, const void * src_str, size_t n);

This will copy data bytewise.

I think memcpy is defined in string.h. There is no need to define it again. Although I think OP meant to write from a buffer to a stream, given the context.
